# Should I use Unity for a "non-game" mobile app?

Tags: unity, android, android-studio

I have some experience with Unity but I always made games only. Right now I have an idea for an app but I don't think Unity is the most efficient way to do it. Probably Android SDK and OpenGL ES would be better but I have to learn them. **So should I learn a new tool or should I stick with what I already know and get this thing done?**

Answer (score 2):

This is very dependent on the app. Unity is not only useful for games, but it should still be something game-like (eg. an architectural walkthrough). For a typical mobile UI app, I would recommend something more like Xamarin

Comment: But which do you think is an easier tool Xamarin or Android SDK?

Answer (score 1):

This questions is a bit overly broad, but the simplest answer is use the best tool for the job. If you don't think Unity can best suit your application, use the technology that will.